# What are the cons of using commas to concat strings with variables instead of using the + operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have always used the `+ operator` to concat strings with other strings or casted variables, but now I noticed that I could use commas (`,`) to what appears to be concatenation that doesn't require casts to variables which weren't strings, and I was wondering what were the cons of using this method over the `+ operator` or when should I not use the commas to concat.

With this code:

```
name = "John"
age = 50
```

If I wanted to print something with those two variables (a string and an integer) with the `+ operator`, I would need to do something like:

```
print("My name is " + name + " and I am " + str(age) + " years old.")
```

To get the following output:

```
My name is John and I am 50 years old.
```

But if I use the commas this way:

```
print("My name is",name," and I am ",str(age),"years old.")
```

I will get the exact same output (including the spaces between the end and start of the srings with the variables).

So I wanted to know what are the cons of doing these cases scenarios with the commas instead of the `+ operator` (if any) and why the commas work the way they work in these cases.

Comment: Coding style preferences? There are also f-strings, and other string formatting methods that you haven't included.

Comment: The commas are just specific to the print function, concatenating or using other string formatting can be applied to any string, whether or not you want to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what has to be considered is the performance of each:

**Using +**

```py
%timeit print("My name is " + name + " and I am " + str(age) + " years old.")
88.8 µs ± 1.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**Using commas**

```py
%timeit print("My name is",name," and I am ",str(age),"years old.")
421 µs ± 16.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Using f-strings**

```
%timeit print(f"My name is {name} and I am {age} years old.")
83.6 µs ± 3.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing is speed because I ran it 100 times through a loop and on average the estimated speed for the + method was always around .09 seconds and the comma method was at .2

if you are doing small things or just using it to debug things then you may use commas for convenience, but if you are trying to optimize it for speed then maybe use + but the time complexity for one print statement is probably O(1) so unless you are doing hundreds of these in a loop, then it shouldn't matter at all really.